# How to change related object when creating object in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to change is_available field in Book object when reservation is being create. I found a way which I am pasting here, but this digging in request looks messy, so as it often is with so mature frameworks as drf there are probably better ways to do that.

So I have serializer.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BookModel
        fields = ["number", "title", "author", "is_available"]


class ReservationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ReservationModel
        fields = ["reserved_by", "book", "started_at", "valid_until"]
```

And views.py

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BookModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    permission_classess = []


class ReservationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ReservationModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReservationSerializer
    permission_classess = []

    def perform_create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().perform_create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        book = BookModel.objects.get(pk=request.data.serializer.instance.book_id)
        book.is_available = False
        book.save()
```

I posted what I did, Please teach me do it better - proper way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.perform_create()* method looks like this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
```

Its only argument is *serializer*, but not *request* as it is in your code and doesnt have *args and **kwargs. You probably mixed it up with *.create()* method.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

If you want to add logic to perform_create method you should do something like:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    reservation = serializer.save()
    book = reservation.book 
    book.is_available = False
    book.save()
```